# Get an array of string from a jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I have a jagged array that contains other 1d string arrays:

```
string[] first = {"one","two"};
string[] second = {"three","four"};
string[][] jagged = {first,second};
```

When I try to get the sub-arrays, they give a null value (I might be doing something wrong):

```
foreach (string[] arr in jagged[][]) {
    // My stuff here
}
```

Did I do something wrong in the array initialization progress or do I have to convert the sub-arrays somehow?

Comment: what specific code is causing what specific error? (yes you might be doing something wrong but how will we know if you don't show what you're doing?)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why are you using arrays like this when .NET has so many better, easier-to-use options for collections of things?  It's a full-featured, object-oriented programming language, not a scripting language.  Take advantage of that.

Comment: Does that even compile?  `foreach (string[] arr in jagged[][])` doesn't look like valid syntax.

Comment: Can you post that brings you null? because this doesn't compile - `... in jagged[][]..`

Comment: For sure `in jagged[][]` is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the foreach part is wrong.
I have tested it like as follows:

```
string[] first = { "one", "two" };
string[] second = {"three","four"};
string[][] jagged = {first,second};

foreach (string[] arr in jagged)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", arr));
}
```

Output:

> **one, two**
>
> **three, four**

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
foreach (string[] arr in jagged)
{
    // My stuff here
}
```

I pasted your code on my local environment and could iterate just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `jagged[][]` in your loop, then possibly you get a type conversion failed message:

> Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'.

Instead use `jagged` in your loop.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] first = {"one","two"};
        string[] second = {"three","four"};
        string[][] jagged = {first,second}; 

        foreach (string[] arr in jagged)
        {
            //Your code
        }
    }
}
```